# Relationships; Cannot get all events from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My models are;

```
class region
has_many :cities
end

class event
belongs_to :city
end

class city
has_many :events
belongs_to :region
end
```

Eventcontroller

```
def index   
    @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
    @cities = @region.cities
    @city = City.find(params[:city_id])
    @events = @city.events  
    @events_by_date = @events.group_by(&:start_on)

  end
```

Page:
region/x/cities/x/events

Shows all the events from the city.

Question: how can i show all events from all the cities on my /region/events page? I created a resources

```
resources :regions do 
  resources :events do
  collection do
     get 'all_events'
  end
end
```

But how I define the "all_event" action in the eventcontroller?

I cannot do this in my eventcontroller @events = @cities.events because event belongs_to :city. Is there a solution for this?

I tried this:

controller:

```
@region = Region.find(1)
@events = Event.includes(:city)
@events_by_date = @events.group_by(&:published_on)
```

View:

```
%ul.property_list
                  - @events_by_date[date].each do |event|
                    %li.restaurant
                      %span.icon
                      %h5
                        = link_to event.title, polymorphic_path([@region, event.city.name, event])
```

error : undefined method `region_Assisi_event_path'

Comment: just make it event.city in the polymorphic path

Comment: thanks.Kyle!..it works..:includes is great feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly all you would need to do:

In your controller

```
   def all_events
     @events = Event.includes(:city)
   end
```

Then in your view, use a block to access all the instances

```
    @events.each do |event|
       event.name
       event.city.name   #not sure if you have a name attribute
```

Comment: i need the values of region, city and event for my links. like this = link_to event.title, polymorphic_path (@region, @city, event)

Comment: What data do you need to show? I am still not sure what needs to be queried

Comment: i want to show a one page all the events from all the cities..with the links pointing to the correct /region/x/cities/events/id path...